# Retrieving ID of all nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j

I want to retrieve the nodes and relationships stored in the Neo4j DB.

This could be done easily using two queries:

```
match (x) return id(x)
match ()-[r]-() return distinct(id(r))
```

A way to do this using a single query would be as follows:

```
match (x) optional match (x)-[r]-() return id(x), id(r)
```

However, this returns pairs such of IDs of x and r, such as: `(123, 11), (100, null)` and so on.

Is there a way to retrieve all the IDs without retrieving such kind of ordered pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use two collections and a WITH:

```
MATCH (n) WITH collect(id(n)) as nodeIds
MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN collect(distinct id(r)) as relIds, nodeIds
```